# How to display error messages in fields of a form that are not valid?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-helper

I'll try to be brief. This is my problem:

In my asp.net project  I have a form page who sents data to a MongoDB. It works well when I fill in all the form. But, now I'm trying implement some validations on the form to warning the user that he forgot a field without fill in.
But, when I click in 'submit' my page return a json fields in a blank html.

Does anyone has an idea what the problem is?

I'm starting in asp.net, so I've no idea to what going on.

Here is my code:

My model "CadastrarModel"

```
public class CadastrarModel 
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string TipoPessoa {get;set;}

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public CadastrarEnderecoModel EnderecoModel { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller "CadastrarController"

```
public class CadastrarController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IServiceRepository _service;
        
        public CadastrarController(IServiceRepository service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [Route("/Cadastrar")]
        public IActionResult Cadastrar()
        {
            return View();    
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Cadastrar")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Cadastrar([FromForm] CadastrarModel cadastrarModel)
        {
            try 
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(cadastrarModel);
                }
                _service.Adicionar(cadastrarModel);
                return View("Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

My cshtml page "Cadastrar.cshtml" - path /Shared/Cadastrar.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cadastrar", "Cadastrar", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom div-half">
    <div style="width: 50%; margin-left: 1%; margin-top: 0px;">
      @Html.ValidationSummary()
      <fieldset class="form-group"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="TipoPessoa">Tipo</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
            <label asp-for="TipoPessoa" class="form-check-label">
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.TipoPessoa, "Vacinado", new { @class = "form-check-input"})
              Vacinado
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.TipoPessoa)
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label asp-for="TipoPessoa" class="form-check-label">
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.TipoPessoa, "Infectado", new { @class = "form-check-input"})
              Infectado
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.TipoPessoa)
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Nome">Nome</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Nome, new {@class="form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "This field cannot be empty", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="DataNascimento">Data de Nascimento</label>
          <div class="form-date">
            @Html.EditorFor(p => p.DataNascimento, new { @class = "dtn"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.Sexo, "Masculino", new { @class = "form-check-input"})
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sexo)
              Masculino
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.Sexo, "Feminino", new { @class = "form-check-input"})
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sexo)
              Feminino
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>    
}
```

The result page when ModelState isn't valid:

[result-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Fca.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your cshtml page `"Cadastrar.cshtml"` path is wrong.It should under the folder:`/View/Cadastrar/xxxx`,like this:

[image]

So what you need to do is:

**1:Create a new folder named `Cadastrar` in your `View` folder.**

**2:Change your action name so that it is not the same as your controller name like `CreateCadastrar` as my screenshots.**

```
public class CadastrarController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Cadastrar")]
    public IActionResult CreateCadastrar()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Cadastrar")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateCadastrar([FromForm] CadastrarModel cadastrarModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(cadastrarModel);
            }
            return View("Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

**3:Create a view in your folder with the same name as your action.**

**4:Change the url in your form like:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCadastrar", "Cadastrar", FormMethod.Post))
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, but it didn't work. I did all the changes you sugest and nothing. It's funny because when I use Visual Studio the project works. But using vscode ( which is where I started develop the project ) the error remains.